# Streaming .jpg stream over RTP with gstreamer or avconv

Tags: streaming, libav, gstreamer

I have image folder where is continuosly updating Photo.jpg (1 FPS).

I need to be able to stream this photo as a continuous video stream via RTsP so it's viewable with VLC.

What would be working solution or query for doing this? I have avconv and gstreamer, I believe both can do the trick, but I have had no luck while trying different launch syntaxes with both of those.

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="C:\\Pictures\\Photo.jpg" loop=true start-index=0 stop-index=0  ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=512,type=video,framerate=1/1 ! identity ! jpegdec ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000

avconv -loop 1 -i "C:\Pictures\photo.jpg" -r 0.1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4 -y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="C:\\Pictures\\Photo.jpg" loop=true start-index=0 stop-index=0  ! image/jpeg,width=640,height=512,type=video,framerate=30/1 ! identity ! jpegdec ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

This seems to work.